# Can the PostScript language be used to fully replace TeX?

Tags: tex-core, postscript

> THE POSTSCRIPT® LANGUAGE is a simple interpretive programming language
>   with powerful graphics capabilities.
>
> ... Because of the importance of text in most applications, the
>   PostScript language provides special capabilities for organizing sets
>   of characters as fonts and for painting characters efficiently.

Can the PostScript Language be  used to fully replace TeX?

Comment: You can compile a simple document with `latex` and `dvips`. After this you can open the ps-file with you favorite text editor.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to "Can intel assembly language fully used to replace C programmming language?". If you are a programmer, you can make full sense of this analogy.

Comment: another analogy: the equivalence is similar to that between a chain-saw and a nail-file.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

PostScript and TeX are designed for different purposes and for this reason one would never exchange one for the other as a replacement. However, from a purely theoretical point of view, both are [Turing-complete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58042/3083) languages and therefore anything that could be expressed in TeX could be also expressed in PostScript and vice versa.

That aside, PostScript is designed as a page description language and TeX as a typesetting system (or language). PostScript deals with lines, characters, rotation of a coordination system, scaling and colors whereas TeX deals with paragraphs, macros to define a markup language and generally provides many high-level services that PostScript hasn't built in: line breaking, hyphenation, breaking paragraphs into pages, footnotes, typesetting of math. Hence, PostScript is much more low level and indeed is one of the target languages for TeX engines: TeX is compiled to PostScript code (via dvips) or to PDF which can be considered a subset of PostScript.

Comment: You know this, so for the audience: the Turing-completeness of TeX and PostScript is a red herring here, as your examples of their respective strengths show.  TeX could provide line breaking, hyphenation, pagination, inserts, and math typesetting without being complete, and still be valuable as a typesetting tool.  PostScript can only do these things by, effectively, building a virtual typesetting machine within itself using its Turing-complete language.  Each language may be capable of reimplementing the other, but *internally* they have different abilities.

Answer (score 13):

There have been many attempts to use Postscript's programming power to implement a fuller document-production environment. AFAIK they all fall short of TeX's line-fitting abilities.

The most basic is the typewriter emulator from the Postscript Tutorial ([Blue Book](http://www-cdf.fnal.gov/offline/PostScript/BLUEBOOK.PDF)), which is then extended in the later Reid books (the [Green Book](http://www-cdf.fnal.gov/offline/PostScript/GREENBK.PDF) and [Thinking In Postscript](http://w3-o.cs.hm.edu/~ruckert/compiler/ThinkingInPostScript.pdf)) to handle embedded control-codes for font changes. These ones operate by reinterpreting the program *stream*, so I often call them "protocol-prolog" style.

Another style is to implement a set of commands with short mnemonic names and implement the document in the RPN syntax. Examples include the [Gonzo Tools](http://www.tinaja.com/post01.shtml), [Practical Postscript](http://www.inf.ufes.br/~thomas/graphics/Postscript/PRACTICAL_POSTSCRIPT.pdf). This is also the primary technique for designing the output for a postscript driver. (The Green Book and Thinking in PostScript are also good resources for this avenue.)

A hybrid of the above approaches is illustrated by [Anastigmatix's tools](http://www.anastigmatix.net/postscript/) which even implement the Knuth-Liang hyphenation algorithm.

Not as powerful as Anastigmatix's tools, but stealing as many of his ideas as I could, [my own effort](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/downloads/detail?name=cv.ps) (disclosure: it's also my resume, nudge nudge.) includes a combination of the above approaches, with a set of mnemonic procedures and embedded control-codes (including arbitrary postscript code) in the strings which contain the text. **Edit:** A more complete program of mine is available for review on [codereview.se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117320/document-formatting-markup-engine-in-postscript). As predicted, it too falls short of tex's line-fitting capability.

On the other end of the issue is capturing the drawing output as a flattened ps document. The traditional tool for this is [still.ps](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/F4tFfdmGkZY/discussion) (in some sense, still.ps is to Distiller what cfront was to a native C++ compiler, by supplementing and extending the existing programmability (the ps interpreter on the one hand, the c compiler on the other). not really going anywhere with this, but I find it interesting). With ghostscript's `-sDEVICE=ps2write` (and `sDEVICE=pdfwrite`) still.ps is largely unnecessary nowadays, but it remains a goldmine of postscript programming idioms and style.

One other notable example is Julian Wiseman's [code for creating Wine-tasting placemats](http://www.jdawiseman.com/papers/placemat/placemat.html). It is a large, heavily customizable postscript "document" which defines many layout
choices.

Comment: A [related experiment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.postscript/LPFC7Ife3Lk/arLn3JFFsE0J) of mine, this time a *ps-markup* -> *formatted ASCII* protocol prolog.

Comment: Yet another [related experiment](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/ibis.ps) of mine.

Comment: A much older [related experiment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.postscript/PryYshNlmFw/_wJHcU5RVjoJ) of mine.