# How big of a file is too big for LaTex?

Tags: pdf

I am a new user to LaTex. Is there an upper limit to the PDF generable from Latex?

What about performance? Suppose I would want to write a 500 pg long book on PDF, at what point is it going to seriously hinder the speed for viewing my PDF file?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [What's the maximum number of pages a PDF produced by pdfTeX can have?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97071/5764)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The objective of your posting is somewhat ambiguous: Are you concerned about the time it may take to *compile* the tex file and create a 500-page pdf file, or about the ease/speed of *viewing* the pdf file in a suitable viewer? Please tell us more about the structure of the file: Is it all just text, are there images (and how large and complex are these images), are there hyperlinked cross-references, are there indexes and bibliographies, etc?

Comment: 500 pages is not really big for latex but it depends on contents

Comment: My 240-page novel takes about 15 seconds to compile, on a machine that is not state of the art. That's using microtype, which no doubt slows it down a bit. Being a novel, it has no graphs, charts, tables, hyperlinks, included images, or bibliography.

Comment: I've typeset the public-domain KJV to be about 850 pages – XeTeX just powers through it like rice in water.

Comment: I've never really boldly gone where no LaTeX-er has gone before; but the only thing I've ever had to sit and wait for is a large (about 400 slides I think) beamer presentation, compiling with xelatex (took about 30 seconds I think)

Comment: I think it would be better to focus this question on how big of an input file TeX can handle – as the title would suggest – otherwise I'd agree that it's a duplicate.