# Example of LaTeX code that does not compile

Tags: cross-referencing, debugging

In the excellent [answer by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288645/61108) to the question [How Does Latex Know the Page Number of a Reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288621/how-does-latex-know-the-page-number-of-a-reference) he said that

> [t]his is not completely foolproof and there are examples around of cleverly written documents that never stabilize: each new run of LaTeX will change the page number associated to a label so it never remains the same. However, the chances that this happens in a real document are pretty small.

Does anyone happen to have such an example of source code?

I see how this works and I thought about this several times, but I was not able to simply create a document where this happens.

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140955/the-latex-runs-with-varioref-never-settle-down-to-a-stable-final-state

Answer (score 0):

Here is an (not real document) example

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
bla\label{yes}
\ifnum\value{page}=1
\makeatletter
\write\@auxout{\string\refstepcounter{page}}
\makeatother\fi
bla bla\pageref{yes}
\end{document}
```