# Write to file: using a macro as the filename

Tags: expansion, auxiliary-files

I'm setting a complex user manual, made of several independant documents. For the overall TOC, I want each document to write some data into a file which is then parsed by the TOC file later.

Here's the point: I want to use a string in a macro as the filename, but it doesn't work. It must have something to do with correct expansion, but I can't find the error...

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

 \newcommand{\docnr}{foo bar}

 \usepackage{stringstrings}
 \newcommand{\tocfile}{../toc/\noblanks{\docnr}.tex}

 \newcommand{\SToc}{
   \newwrite\tempfile
   \immediate\openout\tempfile=\tocfile

   %other stuff
   \immediate\write\tempfile{\docnr}
   %other stuff

   \immediate\closeout\tempfile
}

\begin{document}
   \SToc
   Hello World.
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** A completely different approach that would work for me would be the following: I'm looking for an environment that's full content is expanded as much as possible and then written to the file. By this, I could simply `\input` it in the TOC later. Something like

```
\newcommand{\docnr}{foo bar}
\begin{writetofile}[../toc/\noblanks{\docnr}.tex]
   \textbf{\docnr}
\end{writetofile}
```

And the file foobar.tex would contain

```
\textbf{foo bar}
```

There are many environments to write commands verbatim (without expansion) to a file - I've now searched for the exact opposite, but couldn't find anything. Grmpf!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The file name for `\openout` should be something that fully expands to a string, but `\nospaces` isn't.

Comment: Do you need page numbers in the `\tocfile`?

Comment: Heiko: No, it's the front page of the ringfile and onyl gives the chapter numbers by a custom counter. I've got it running now quite fine, except that I can't put the file "upstream" with the ../toc/foobar.tex -- seems that I'm only allowed to write into the current folder or downstream of that.

Comment: Found something about the upstream navigation here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116926/can-filecontents-write-an-external-file-in-a-parent-directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel has a command `\zap@space`, which is expandable and can be used in file names, e.g.:

```
\newcommand*{\docnr}{foo bar}

\makeatletter
\edef\docnr@wosp{\docnr\space}
\newcommand{\tocfile}{}
\edef\tocfile{../toc/\expandafter\zap@space\docnr@wosp\@empty.tex}
\makeatother

\typeout{[tocfile=\tocfile]}
```

Result:

```
[tocfile=../toc/foobar.tex]
```

### Writing without page numbers

When page numbers are not needed, then deferred writing is not needed and we can use `\immediate\write`. LaTeX's protection mechanism is supported by

```
\let\protect\noexpand
```

while writing the entry. Then `\textbf{\docnr}` becomes `\textbf  {foo bar}`. TeX adds a space after command names and the other space comes from LaTeX's protected commands, which expand to a macro with the same name except that a trailing space was added to the macro name.

Fragile macros can be protected by prefixing it with `\protect` as usual. `\string` can also be used, it avoids the space after the command name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\docnr}{foo bar}

\makeatletter
\edef\docnr@wosp{\docnr\space}
\newcommand{\tocfile}{}
\edef\tocfile{\expandafter\zap@space\docnr@wosp\@empty.tex}
\makeatother

% toc file management
\makeatletter
\if@filesw
  \let\toc@handle\relax
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\addtotoc}[1]{%
    \ifx\toc@handle\relax
      \newwrite\toc@handle
      \immediate\openout\toc@handle=\tocfile\relax
    \fi
    \begingroup
      \let\protect\noexpand
      \immediate\write\toc@handle{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \newcommand*{\closetoc}{%
    \immediate\closeout\toc@handle
  }%
\else
  \newcommand{\addtotoc}[1]{}%
  \newcommand*{\closetoc}{}%
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \addtotoc{\textbf{\docnr}, %
    written via macro \string\verb|\string\addtotoc|.}
  \closetoc
  \input{\tocfile}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

File `foobar.tex`:

```
\textbf  {foo bar}, written via macro \verb|\addtotoc|.
```

The file can be read before the first `\addtotoc` and after `\closetoc`.

### Deferred writing with page numbers

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\docnr}{foo bar}

\makeatletter
\edef\docnr@wosp{\docnr\space}
\newcommand{\tocfile}{}
\edef\tocfile{\expandafter\zap@space\docnr@wosp\@empty.tex}
\makeatother

% toc file management
\makeatletter
\if@filesw
  \let\toc@handle\relax
  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\addtotoc}{%
    \ifx\toc@handle\relax
      \newwrite\toc@handle
      \immediate\openout\toc@handle=\tocfile\relax
    \fi
    \protected@write\toc@handle{}% + argument of \addtotoc
  }%
  \newcommand*{\closetoc}{%
    \closeout\toc@handle
  }%
\else
  \newcommand{\addtotoc}[1]{}%
  \newcommand*{\closetoc}{}%
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Hello World!

  \addtotoc{\textbf{\docnr} on page \thepage,
    written via macro \string\verb|\string\addtotoc|.}
  \closetoc
  \newpage
  \input{\tocfile}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result deferred writing]

File `foobar.tex`:

```
\textbf  {foo bar} on page 1, written via macro \verb|\addtotoc|.
```

The file can be read before the first `\addtotoc` and after the page, where the deferred `\closeout` is called.

Comment: Servus Heiko & Christian! This is quick and easy -- and just works fine. Thanks a lot! If anyone has an idea for my alternative approach, this would also be highly appreciated ;-)   Regards, Vic

Answer (score 2):

You could try this with `xstring` and `\StrDel`, preprocessing the filename first and storing it to `\tocfile` macro.

The macro `\noblanks` from `stringstrings` isn't expandable, unfortunately. (Have a look into `stringstrings` package or use `texdef` to see this)

Some other note: It might occur that `pdflatex` will refuse to write on pathnames starting with a `.`.

Try to locate `texmf.cnf` and add this line at the end:

```
openout_any = a
```

However, this might be a security breach.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}


\newwrite\tempfile

\newcommand{\docnr}{foo bar}

%\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{xstring}
\gdef\tocfile{}
\StrDel[0]{../toc/\docnr.tex}{ }[\tocfile]


\newcommand{\SToc}{%
  \immediate\openout\tempfile=\tocfile
  % other stuff
  \immediate\write\tempfile{\docnr}
  % other stuff
  \immediate\closeout\tempfile
}

\begin{document}
\SToc
Hello World.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Can filecontents write an external file in a parent directory?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116926/can-filecontents-write-an-external-file-in-a-parent-directory) for the problem of writing files in directories above the current one or given an explicit path.

This said, we can solve your problem with an easy set of macros in `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_new:N \g_victor_output_stream

\tl_new:N \l_victor_filename_tl

%\tl_const:Nn \c_victor_prefix_tl { ../toc/ } % use this one
\tl_const:Nn \c_victor_prefix_tl { ./ } % for the test

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_open:Nn { NV }

\NewDocumentCommand{\SToc}{ O{\docnr} }
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_victor_filename_tl { \c_victor_prefix_tl #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_victor_filename_tl { ~ } { }
  \iow_open:NV \g_victor_output_stream \l_victor_filename_tl
  \STocStuffA
  \iow_now:Nx \g_victor_output_stream { #1 }
  \STocStuffB
  \iow_close:N \g_victor_output_stream
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\docnr}{foo bar}

\newcommand{\STocStuffA}{} % for the test
\newcommand{\STocStuffB}{} % for the test

\begin{document}

\SToc

Hello World.

\end{document}
```

The macros `\STocStuffA` and `\STocStuffB` will contain what you need to be done before and after the write operation as hinted in your code.

Just change the prefix to get a location different from the current working directory (the one where the main TeX file belongs).

You can call `\SToc` with no optional argument or with one, that will be used instead of the default `\docnr`. Possibly you don't need this feature, but it's so easy to add it that I didn't want to lose this opportunity for adding flexibility to your macros.

We prepare the string to be passed to `\openout` (in `expl3` it becomes `\iow_open:Nn`, which we use a variant of) by removing all spaces. In the write operation, we can directly use the argument (`\docnr` by default).

---

Note about your code: don't put the `\newwrite` declaration in the macro `\SToc`, because you'd waste an output stream at each call. So `\newwrite\tempfile` must go outside the definition of `\SToc` (and a more specific name than `\tempfile` should be used).

Comment: Hi egreg! Isn't this just using LaTeX3-Syntax to loophole the reasonably "paranoid" setting in texmf.cnf? I'm afraid that one day this will be blocked as well. At the moment I'm working with "openout_any = a" (resp. MIKTEX_ALLOWUNSAFEOUTPUTFILES=1). --Regards, Vic

Comment: @Victor You can't overcome the setting in `texmf.cnf` with macros of any kind. I used a prefix for convenience and set it to `./` for testing; the other possibility won't work unless you set `openout_any=a`.