# Writing files to another directories

Tags: external-files, write

I need to write files in a specific directory on the file system where I have access to. But even if I can write files in the current working directory or any sub-directories, it seems that I am stock there.

For example, let's say that my **test.tex** file is located in this directory:

```
c:\SomeDirectory\test.tex
```

Is it possible to create a file in a directory I have access to (I created it myself), for example this one?

```
c:\AnotherDirectory\results.txt
```

Currently, I am using this code, and it doesn't work:

```
\newwrite\file
%\immediate\openout\file="results.txt"  % This works when uncommented
\immediate\openout\file="c:/AnotherDirectory/results.txt"  % Does not work...
\immediate\write\file{Line 1}
\immediate\write\file{Line 2}
\immediate\write\file{Line 3}
\closeout\file
```

I get this error message:

```
I can't write on file `"c:/AnotherDirectory/results.txt"'
```

Am I restricted by my LaTeX editor? Maybe I am not using the proper syntax?

Thanks!

Dave

Comment: This is a deliberate security setting, which you can turn off but which most of us would not recommend.

Comment: That makes sense and I agree with this! But where exactly can I turn it off? I need to export some results next week, so if I can turn it off only for a few days, it would make my life easier...

Comment: For your own safety: try not to modify the actual config file and instead do like [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116926/can-filecontents-write-an-external-file-in-a-parent-directory#comment259411_116926) so that you are using doing the override temporarily.