# What type of Chomsky hierarchy is TeX?

Tags: tex-core, grammar

There are four types of chomsky hierarchy (specified for formal languages):

```
Type-0  Recursively enumerable
Type-1  Context-sensitive
Type-2  Context-free
Type-3  Regular
```

I consider that, it should be the **type-0**. This type is represented by **Turing machine**. I think, that it is because of the dynamic changing tokens during runtime, dynamic changing of the meaning of macros, calculating Lambda calcul (what should be the most *important*).

Do you have any advice?

Comment: It's usually said that TeX is Turing-complete indeed, but I've never seen a formal proof of that.  Someone here should have a reference.

Comment: Recommend you read this entire question carefully. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58042/are-there-any-disadvantages-of-tex-being-turing-complete

Comment: There is a proof that LaTeX is Turing complete [here](http://en.literateprograms.org/Turing_machine_simulator_%28LaTeX%29). I obtained the link from [Antal S-Z's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4205) explaining why TeX cannot have a BNF grammar. Not sure if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2946758) might be helpful.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4201/17423

Comment: The proposed question is **related** not **duplicate**